# How to set the value of a snapshot from firebase realtime to a variable on flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use values from my database to set values for temp1 and umid1 variables in the code below.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(...)
    body: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Column(children: [
                createTempClock(temp1, "Temperatura 1"),
                createUmidClock(umid1, "Umidade 1")
              ]),
              ],
          ),
        )
       )
      }
```

To access the database I am using the following code

```
getDbValueAsNumber(String path, String grandeza, context) async {
    DatabaseReference refer = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(path);
    refer.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      final Object? data = event.snapshot.value;
      return ((data as Map)[grandeza]);
    });
  }
```

I can use getDbValueAsNumber to print the values, but when I try to apply it to a variable I encounter the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIneT.png).

I tried countless ways. Two of the ones I came closest (I think) to were
[text](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/read-and-write/)
[text](https://anmol-gupta.medium.com/crud-operations-with-the-firebase-realtime-database-in-flutter-e19617c54528)

Comment: you are using "async" in your code, can you include "await"? kindly let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your setting the values that you read from Firebase to normal fields in your class/widget. This works, but you need to tell Flutter to re-render the UI based on the updated values. To do this, ensure yours is a `StatefulWidget` and call `setState()` after you set the value to the field(s).

For more on this, see the Flutter documentation on its [`StatefulWidget` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and on [creating a stateful widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/interactivity#creating-a-stateful-widget).